# Determine whether a regular surjective map is finite

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Consider the regular map between affine closed sets $f \colon \mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathcal{Z}(y^2-x^3) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$ given by

$f(t) = (t^2,t^3)$.

$f$ is obviously a dominant map. I want to know if it is a finite map.

Since $f$ is a dominant map, it induces an inclusion $f^* \colon \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}[t]$ given by $f^*\bar{p}(x,y) = p(t^2,t^3)$. How can I see whether the extension of rings $f^*\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3) \subseteq \mathbb{C}[t]$ is integral?

Comment: The image of $f^*$ is the subring $B=\mathbf C[t^2,t^3]$. You just want to show that $t$ (why can I just check this one element?) satisfies a monic polynomial with coefficients in $B$.

Comment: t satisfies, for example $s^3-t^3 \in B[s]$, where $B = \mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$. Moreover, I can just check $t$ because $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is generated as a $B$-algebra by the element $t \in \mathbb{C}[t]$.
Right?

Comment: Yes! It's fine.